# Working with CSV file with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm working on a powershell script to do below steps:

1. Get data from database and export to excel file (i use .csv file)
2. Reformat color in the CSV file (color, merge cells, font etc)
3. Save CSV file
4. Send the content of csv file as body into email (with all the format retained)

I have done step 1-3

now i have concern for #4, do I need to reformat again after I export from CSV to email body?

also, is there any way to use RBG color in powershell? I used colorindex but it's really limited to 56 color only

Comment: "Does CSV allow format?" No, it does not. It supports only plain text.

Comment: @AxelRichter  hi Axel, i thought the same but just now i changed my code to save into a new CSV file , and seems to work ( the format retained).  


         $WorkBook.Saveas("I:\SCRIPT\IPCNewScript\ResultFinal.csv",1)
$objExcel.Quit()

Comment: After `WorkBook.SaveAs("I:\SCRIPT\IPCNewScript\ResultFinal.csv",1)` the `ResultFinal.csv` will no more be a CSV file but a Microsoft Office Excel 2003 file only named ResultFinal.csv.

Comment: @AxelRichter, the type of that file is still showing as 'Microsoft Excel Comma Separated Values File (.csv)'. So it is not not a CSV?

Comment: What happens if you are opening it using a text editor?

Comment: @AxelRichter i see. text editor cant read it. Thank you!. Let me try to see if I can directly send this into email body, and keep the format retained. if not i may have to send the orginal CSV into email, then reformat in HTML

Comment: @ella : an excel file with a csv ectension is NOT the same as a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specs for CSV don't address color, font, or the like at all.  If you use Export-csv, all of this info will be lost.

You may be able to get what you want by saving it as a  rich text file,  or by exporting it to some formatted text scheme like HTML.  But this may obscure the CSV structure of your data.